# Almost surely divergent series

Tags: probability

Let $(X_{n})$ be a seqence of iid random variables such that $X_{n} \sim \mathcal{N}(\xi, \sigma^2)$, $\xi > 0$. I want to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_{i}}{i} = \infty$  almost surely. I am not quite sure how to do this. I tried using Kolmogorovs three series criterion.

Comment: This seems to be a restatement of a Gambler's Ruin problem.

Comment: okay. Could you specify that comment

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A,B$ are independent, $A\sim \mathcal{N}(\xi,\sigma^2)$, and $B\sim \mathcal{N}(\eta,\tau^2)$. Then
$$
tA\sim \mathcal{N}(t\xi,(t\sigma)^2),\qquad A+B\sim \mathcal{N}(\xi+\eta,\sigma^2+\tau^2).
$$

Consequently, it follows that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{X_i}{i}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\xi\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i},\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}\right).
$$
Thus as $n\to\infty$, the mean tends to $\infty$ while the variance is bounded by $\sigma^2\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Hence the r.v. tends to $\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Why is that sufficient for almost sure convergence?

Comment: I just realized why this is enough. Tank you :)